# Does styrene really react with KMnO4?

Tags: organic-chemistry

> A benzene derivative $ \ce{C_8H_x} $  did not produce white precipitate with the
> ammonical silver nitrate solution but decolorised the cold dilute
> alkaline $\ce{KMnO4}$ solution. The compound is having _____ number of
> hydrogen atoms.

1. The absence of white precipitate indicates it is not an alkyne.
2. The benzene ring must have an alkene group attached with it such that it decolourises $\ce{KMnO4}$

Now for the question, the answer key tells it must be styrene, however I argue that the answer should be one homologous higher than styrene, because styrene's resonance doesn't allow it to react with $\ce{KMnO4}$.

Is my reasoning right?

Comment: No, it would react just fine. Also, the next one in the homologous series would be C9, not C8.

Comment: Oh my, I think I overlooked that part about $C_8$. Due apologies. But isn't the double bond in conjugation with the benzene? Shouldn't the electron delocalization prevent further attack?

Comment: It is in conjugation, but that's not enough to prevent it from most attacks.

Comment: Hmm makes sense. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Styrene has been reported to react with potassium permanganate to yield 1-phenyl-1,2-ethanediol (at room temperature, albeit promoted by either [ultrasound](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(98)01671-2) or [hydrogen peroxide](https://doi.org/10.1039/C5RA01646K)), phenylglyoxylic acid (albeit [at 70 °C](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01265a511)), and benzaldehyde (at room temperature, albeit in the presence of [alumina](https://doi.org/10.1055/s-2001-16760)). None of the above-mentioned methods strictly adhere to the "cold dilute alkaline KMnO4 solution" mentioned. Yet, I argue that styrene is more than happy to react with KMnO4 if given a little nudge. Meanwhile, phenylacetylene also reacts with KMnO4, yet again requiring a little heat ([refluxing DMC](https://doi.org/10.1055/s-1978-24783)).
Nonetheless, as @jimchmst pointed out, phenylacetylene couldn't be the right answer because it reacts with [silver nitrate](https://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV5P0517).This leads us to conclude that the correct answer is styrene.

References:

1. https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(98)01671-2
2. https://doi.org/10.1039/C5RA01646K
3. https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01265a511
4. https://doi.org/10.1055/s-2001-16760
5. https://doi.org/10.1055/s-1978-24783
6. https://orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV5P0517